# How to run background.js only on specific links?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a chrome extension that closes tabs when they're loaded if their links contain specific words / strings. My intention was to solve that using the `matches` statement in the `manifest.json`. Unfortuantely this doesn't work. My `manifest.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Chrome Extension",
  "version": "0.1",
   "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
       "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
          "matches": [
               "https://www.google.de/",
                "https://sghm.eu/iserv/login"
          ],
          "scripts": ["background.js"],
          "persistent": true
  }
}
```

And my `background.js` like this:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
      console.log('background running');
      chrome.tabs.remove(tabId, function() { });
  }
})
```

In my opinion I've expressed clearly that the script only runs on `google` and `sghm.eu`, so why does it run on every loaded page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problems:

- The "background" section can't have "matches" as you can see in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages). The background script runs in a separate hidden background page that's not related to tabs.
- The content script declared in your manifest.json runs on all URLs. For the task you want to achieve you don't need a content script at all.

Solution consists of several steps:

1. Remove "content_scripts" section
2. Remove "matches" from "background" section
3. Switch to an event page script by specifying `"persistent": false`
4. Add ["webNavigation"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) permission in manifest.json and use it to detect URL navigation.

background.js:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(closeTab, {
  url: [
    {urlPrefix: 'https://www.google.de/'},
    {urlPrefix: 'https://sghm.eu/iserv/login'},
  ]
});

function closeTab(e) {
  if (!e.frameId) {
    chrome.tabs.remove(e.tabId);
  }
}
```